# No View found for fragment YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

I am trying to load YouTube videos in one of the tab of my screen.The tab is basically a fragment named `SocialFragmentTab`. I am using `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` here. I am getting the id of youtube video which should be loaded in the YouTube player .But while running the code ,I am getting the error :

> No view found for id 0x7f0c00f6
> (com.almaybay.almabay:id/youtube_fragment) for fragment
> YouTubePlayerSupportFragment{860e2da #0 id=0x7f0c00f6}

Please help me resolve the issue.The code is :
**1. SocialFragmentTab.java**'

```
 public class SocialFragmentTab extends Fragment {
    Context context;
    private static final String TAG = DashboardActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListSocialAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItemSocial> feedItems;
    //private String URL_FEED = "http://192.168.2.17:8000/api/v1/user-timeline-social/?access_token=yp1faO6Co6ISkrmO1nl1eUPMhjorua&user=491&type1=story&type2=story&start=0&limit=10&format=json";
    private String URL_FEED_Social_Timeline = "";
    AlmabayDatabase almabayDatabase;
    APIConfiguration apiConfiguration;
    int uid;
    String accessToken, api;
    private ConfigYoutubeAPI configYoutubeAPI;
    private YouTubePlayer YPlayer;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_socialtab, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItemSocial>();
        listAdapter = new FeedListSocialAdapter(getActivity(), feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        almabayDatabase = new AlmabayDatabase(getActivity());
        // Getting userID from database
        uid = almabayDatabase.getUserID();
        //Getting accesss token from database
        accessToken = almabayDatabase.getAccessToken();
        apiConfiguration = new APIConfiguration();
        api = apiConfiguration.getApi();
        //Log.e("API", api);
        URL_FEED_Social_Timeline = api + "/webservice/userSocialTimeline" + "?" + "user_id=" + uid + "&" + "access_token=" + accessToken + "&" + "before_post_id=1364&after_post_id=1354";
        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Cache.Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED_Social_Timeline);
        context = getActivity();
        // making fresh volley request and getting json
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_FEED_Social_Timeline, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                //Log.e("JSONArraySocial", String.valueOf(jsonArray));
                longInfo(String.valueOf(jsonArray));
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Log.e("Volley Test", String.valueOf(jsonObject.getInt("id")));
                        parseJsonFeed(jsonObject);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Log.e("Error Test", volleyError.getMessage());
            }
        });

        // Adding request to volley request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);

        // Creates a youtube fragment
        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
        configYoutubeAPI = new ConfigYoutubeAPI();
        String YoutubeDeveloperKey = configYoutubeAPI.getYouTubeAPI();
        Log.e("YouTubeDeveloperKey",YoutubeDeveloperKey);
        // Initialize a youtube player which can be used to play videos and control video playback
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                if (!b) {
                    YPlayer = youTubePlayer;
                    YPlayer.setFullscreen(false);
                    YPlayer.loadVideo(configYoutubeAPI.getYouTubeVideoID());
                    YPlayer.play();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error in loading video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        return view;
    }


    public void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        //Log.e("JSONObjectSocial", String.valueOf(jsonObject));
        FeedItemSocial item = new FeedItemSocial();
        // Getting values from JSON data
        try {
            String text = jsonObject.getString("text");
            String timestamp = jsonObject.getString("timestamp");
            JSONObject jsonPublisher = jsonObject.getJSONObject("publisher");
            String name = jsonPublisher.getString("name");
            String media_type = jsonObject.getString("media_type");
            if (media_type.equals("youtube")) {
                JSONObject jsonMedia = jsonObject.getJSONObject("media");
                String youtubeID = jsonMedia.getString("id");
                Log.e("YoutubeID", youtubeID);
                configYoutubeAPI = new ConfigYoutubeAPI();
                configYoutubeAPI.setYouTubeVideoID(youtubeID);
            }


            String visitor_profilePic = jsonPublisher.getString("thumbnail_url");

            //Adding values to the FeedItemSocial
            item.setVisitor_status(text);
            item.setTimeStamp(timestamp);
            item.setVisitor_name(name);
            item.setVisitor_profilePic(visitor_profilePic);

            // Adding items to the list
            feedItems.add(item);

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // To display long String in the Logcat
    public static void longInfo(String str) {
        if (str.length() > 4000) {
            Log.e("JSONArrayResponse", str.substring(0, 4000)); // Displaying substring from 0 to 3999.
            longInfo(str.substring(4000)); // Substring from 4000 onwards
        } else
            Log.e("JSONArrayResponse", str);
    }


}
```

**2. feed_item_social.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right">

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/profilePicVisitor"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"></com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_profile_name"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timestamp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/timestamp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_timestamp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imgLike"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/likes_social" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtLike"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Like" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imgShare"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/share2_social" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtShare"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Share" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imgNotification"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/notification_social" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtNotification"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Get Notification" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtStatusMsg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top" />

        <com.almaybay.almabay.FeedImageView
            android:id="@+id/feedImage1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLikeCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/likes_social" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtCommentCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtShareCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/share2_social" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**3.ConfigYoutubeAPI.java**

```
    public class ConfigYoutubeAPI {
    String youTubeAPI = "AIzaSy...";
    String youTubeVideoID;

    public String getYouTubeAPI() {
        return youTubeAPI;
    }

    public String getYouTubeVideoID() {
        return youTubeVideoID;
    }

    public void setYouTubeVideoID(String youTubeVideoID) {
        this.youTubeVideoID = youTubeVideoID;
    }
}
```

**4. Logcat**

```
 Process: com.almaybay.almabay, PID: 31973
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c00f6 (com.almaybay.almabay:id/youtube_fragment) for fragment YouTubePlayerSupportFragment{860e2da #0 id=0x7f0c00f6}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1018)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1983)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1061)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:545)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17429)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17429)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17429)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17429)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17429)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17429)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17429)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2815)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17429)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5786)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.
```

Comment: Try to replace a layout that doesn't have parents,  that is to say, the parent layout of the activity, I think that's why the recommendation is use a new activity when you work with Youtube player. As side note, even if the player is running if you put something above the player this stops, so the api has many checks to work correctly.